# Left Outer Join on Streams in Pyspark is dropping the non-matching values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming

I have a dlt pipeline in which i have to join 2 streams with a left outer join. and save this as a temp table (futher there will be more code that will use temp table data to make silver table).

But, after joining the stream, it only keeps the matching records from both tables, while the records from left table that doesn't have matching id's don't appear in the temp table.

Code is as below,

```
def create_temp_table():
        
        @dlt.table(
            name=f"temp_{target_table}",
            comment="Temporary table",
            temporary=True,
            table_properties={"quality": "temp"},
        )
        
        def load_dynamic_table():
            
            table1 = f"LIVE.{table_prefix}_{source_table1}"

            df1 = (
                spark.readStream.format("delta")
                .option("ignoreChanges", "true")
                .table(table1)
            )

            df2 = /* This stream is created by applying some filters on df1 and renaming key and timestamp columns The below join is done basically to calculate a derived column */
         

            # Add watermarks
            df1 = df1.withWatermark("timestampcol", "5 minutes")
            df2 = df2.withWatermark("tmstampcol", "5 minutes")

            # Join both dfs based of id column from df1 and id2 column from df2. Also to note that the timestamp values in both streams are going to be exactly the same and there will not be any delay as df2 is derived from df1.
            df = df1.join(df2, 
                      expr("id= id2 AND timestampcol >= tmstampcol AND timestampcol <= tmstampcol + interval 5 minutes"),
                      "left"
                     )
            
           

            return df #this writes the temp table
```

I have tried the watermark and time constraints from 5 seconds to even 15 minutes, but it never writes all values

As per spark docs below, this is a caveat, but how do we make sure that even the non matching records are written to the temp table
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#outer-joins-with-watermarking

> The outer NULL results will be generated with a delay that depends on the specified watermark delay and the time range condition. This is because the engine has to wait for that long to ensure there were no matches and there will be no more matches in future.