# Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets, How to resolve this?

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

In my code there is a specific requirement due to which i had to use partition by on a streaming dataframe.
But gives me following error

> Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets

How do I resolve this issue, can anyone help ??

```
df = (
                spark.readStream.format("delta")
                .option("ignoreChanges", "true")
                .table(table)
            )
         
            window_spec = Window.partitionBy("id1","id2","id3").orderBy("BronzeLoadDateTime")
            df = df.withColumn("KEY", when(col("key_indicator") == "KID", col("key_value")).otherwise(None))
            df = df.withColumn("KEY", first("KEY", ignorenulls=True).over(window_spec))
            return df
```

Comment: yes, i am using azure databricks. this code is part of dlt pipeline..

Answer (score 0):

Spark Structured Streaming only allows for time-based windowing and does not support traditional SQL windowing using '`over()`'.

Spark Structured Streaming cannot divide all the data based on a specific column.However, this is not feasible since streams consist of unbounded input data.

An alternative approach is to use `groupBy()` in Spark Structured Streaming.

It's important to note that `groupBy()` is a stateful operation, which means it can't be implemented in append mode unless you include a timestamp column in the list of columns you intend to perform the groupBy operation on.

```
df_result_stream = df.withWatermark("createdAt", "10 minutes" ) \
              .groupBy( F.col('Id'), window(F.col("createdAt"), self.acceptable_time_difference)) \
              .agg(F.max(F.col('createdAt')).alias('maxCreatedAt'))
```

In the above example, createdAt is a column of type timestamp. It's crucial to remember that in this scenario, we need to use withWatermark on the timestamp column beforehand.

[image]

This is necessary because Spark is not able to store states endlessly.

Note that although `groupBy` doesn't work precisely like windowing, you can achieve the desired functionality with a basic `join` or a custom function using `mapGroupsWithState`.

Windows always needs time-based data, but Spark Structured Streaming no.

You can set up a Spark Structured Streaming job with the trigger "**as soon as possible**" and then group the data based on a specific time window.

[Know more Structured Streaming Programming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#structured-streaming-programming-guide)

Comment: When I used a basic left join to achieve the results, I am facing an issue where it only keeps the matching values, even though in left join non matching values of left table should be returned as well. Do you know why that code happen ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77267671/left-outer-join-on-streams-in-pyspark-is-dropping-the-non-matching-values